# Binding In c++ programming Language

Tags: c++

*Can any one explain this statement in a way that a 6 year old boy can understand?*

> Connecting the function call to the function body is called Binding. When it is done before the program is run, its called Early Binding or Static Binding or Compile-time Binding.

*I wanted to know about Early and Late binding. I couldn't get what the above statement is saying.*

Comment: @user2864740 i wouldn't have posted this question if i was able to understand ur link...

Comment: @user2864740 nothing at all ,plz explain in a simple way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two cases

```
void fun();
```

This is early binding, because compiler knows address of function to call.

Suppose you have `fun` in base class, which is virtual,

```
virtual void fun();
```

Also you have fun in derived class,

```
    class Base
    {
      public:
      virtual void fun(){//some code};

    };

     class Der : public Base
    {
      public:
      virtual void fun(){//some code};

    };
```

Now which fun will be called is depends on how you call function.

Let say,

```
int main()
{
 Base *b = new Base(); 
 b->fun(); //base version will be called

 Ber *d = new Der(); 
 b->fun(); //der version will be called

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I need to update my notion of the term "late binding" in context >_< It means something different in .NET (and even subtly different in Java).